# Logging failure with multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging, multiprocessing

I am trying to implement logging with multiprocessing for our application(flask). We use python2.7, I am using the concept of queues to keep log requests from all the forks and logging records present in the queue. I followed this [approach](https://mattgathu.github.io/multiprocessing-logging-in-python/). Only change from that link is I am using TimedRotatatingFileHandler instead of RotatingFileHandler. This is my [dictconfig](http://dpaste.com/16EMG41)

I am initializing the logger before initializing the forks and in code in the following way

```
    from flask import Flask
    from tornado.wsgi import WSGIContainer 
    from tornado.httpserver import HTTPServer
    from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop


    path = 'share/log_test/logging.yaml'
    if os.path.exists(path):
        with open(path, 'rt') as f:
            config = yaml.load(f.read())
        logging.config.dictConfig(config)

    logger = logging.getLogger('debuglog') # problem starts if i keep this statement

    app = Flask(__name__)
    init_routes(app) # initialize our routes
    server_conf = config_manager.load_config(key='server')
    logger.info("Logging is set up.") # only this line gets logged and other log statement to be logged by forks in code with same logger are not writing to the file.

    http_server = HTTPServer(WSGIContainer(app))

    http_server.bind(server_conf.get("PORT")) # port to listen
    http_server.start(server_conf.get("FORKS")) # number of forks
    IOLoop.current().start()
```

The problem I am facing is if i use getLogger in the code before initializing the forks, the forks are not writing logs to the logfile, only log statements before initializing forks are being logged. If I remove the `logging.getLogger('debuglog')` , forks are logging correctly.

I paused the execution flow and verified if the handler is assigned to logger or not but that seems to be fine

Why this strange behavior is observed?

**Update:** when I use another logger with the same file to write and everything is working fine. But when i use same logger it's not working. Anything related to RLock?

Answer (score 0):

I got a workaround for this solution finally. I removed the concept of queues in the implementation and just printing then and there itself after receiving the log record.

```
    def emit(self, record):
        try:
            s = self._format_record(record)
            self._handler.emit(record) #emitting here itself
            # self.send(s) #stopped sending it to queue 
        except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
            raise
        except:
            self.handleError(record)
```

which seems to be working fine with the following testing

`8 workers - 200 requests - 50 concurrency`

Comment: @Vinay Sajip, can you please help me in this, with this hack, it's not logging all the time, for sometimes its logging and sometimes it is not responding